# Is it possible to select a <path> based on a click on <g>?

Tags: d3.js, legend

What I want to do is

1. I want to click on the legend (anywhere on both rect and text) to show/hide that segment of data. I can do it on rect alone or text alone but not on both of them (on 'g'). So, I'd like to know if this is doable.
2. After I click, I also want to retrieve the text/category from that legend element too as I need re-assign the original colour in `colorScale()`.

Take this [snippet](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/gE1xQu), for example, I want to click on 'g' of class 'legend' and also get the text that attach to the rect element.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind the data to the `<g>` element, there is really no difference between clicking on the rectangle and clicking on the text. In both situations you can retrieve the datum.

However, as we're going to use a property named `clicked`...

```
legend.each(function(d) {
    d.clicked = false;
})
```

... to deal with the clicks, the best idea is changing the data bound to an array of objects:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') // NEW
    .data(dataset)
```

Change the rectangles and the texts accordingly, to use `d.label`.

Then, in the click function, we just do:

```
legend.on("click", function(d) {
    d.clicked = !d.clicked;
    console.log("Category is: " + d.label)
    path.filter(function(e) {
        return e.data.label === d.label
    }).style("opacity", d.clicked ? 0 : 1)
})
```

Which:

1. Toggle the `clicked` property;
2. filter the paths according to the label;
3. Style them according to the `clicked` property.

This is the code with that change:

```js
var dataset = [{
  label: 'Abulia',
  count: 10
}, {
  label: 'Betelgeuse',
  count: 20
}, {
  label: 'Cantaloupe',
  count: 30
}, {
  label: 'Dijkstra',
  count: 40
}];

var width = 360;
var height = 360;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var donutWidth = 75;
var legendRectSize = 18; // NEW
var legendSpacing = 4; // NEW

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
    ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
  .outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })
  .sort(null);

var path = svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return color(d.data.label);
  });

var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') // NEW
  .data(dataset) // NEW
  .enter() // NEW
  .append('g') // NEW
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  // NEW
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) { // NEW
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing; // NEW
    var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2; // NEW
    var horz = -2 * legendRectSize; // NEW
    var vert = i * height - offset; // NEW
    return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')'; // NEW
  }); // NEW

legend.append('rect') // NEW
  .attr('width', legendRectSize) // NEW
  .attr('height', legendRectSize) // NEW
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return color(d.label)
  }) // NEW
  .style('stroke', function(d) {
    return color(d.label)
  }); // NEW

legend.append('text') // NEW
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing) // NEW
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing) // NEW
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  }); // NEW

legend.each(function(d) {
  d.clicked = false;
})

legend.on("click", function(d) {
  d.clicked = !d.clicked;
  console.log("Category is: " + d.label)
  path.filter(function(e) {
    return e.data.label === d.label
  }).style("opacity", d.clicked ? 0 : 1)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 10% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```